# Query trig file with Sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki, tdb

I have a .trig file which I want to query without pushing to Jena Fuseki. 
However when I try to load the model using:

`Model model= FileManager.get().loadModel("filepath/demo.trig");`

certain links in the original TRIG file  are getting lost.

this is the code snippet:

```
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(RDFProject.class.getClassLoader());
Model model= FileManager.get().loadModel("filePath/demo.trig");
model.write(System.out);
```

Is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: Don't see how you'd expect to load TriG into a single model. As I understand it a model corresponds to a single graph. Also, 'certain links' getting lost isn't much of a clue. Are they the graph URIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RDFDataMgr` to load a dataset (not a model) and query that.

```
Dataset ds = RDFDataMgr.loadDataset("filepath/demo.trig");
```